# What kind of replacement timer do I need for my sauna?

Tags: timer

I have an electric sauna from the 90s with a mechanical timer that is malfunctioning. The last time I used it, when I turned it all the way to 60 min, it shut off, so I backed it off a bit. It ran to 0, but did not shut off. I think I need to replace it. Can I fix it?

The current one looks like a puck and is housed in a box with the mechanical thermostat. I don’t care if the new timer fits in the box.
What kind of timer do I need and can I get it at an electrical wholesaler?

[image]

face of timer in box. box also has light switch and thermostat control

here are some pics of the heater spec and the timer

[image: heater spec]

[image: mechanical timer]

Comment: A few pictures of the timer will be needed to help you out.  Timers are pretty common but we need to see what you got.

Comment: Looks like you'll need to visit this help page as you seem to have two accounts now. https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts

Comment: Can anyone else read the nameplate? It looks so small here that I can't read a thing on it.

Comment: Because somehow the thumbnails got posted instead of the pix.

Answer (score 3):

The fact you stated the last time you used this timer it ran down to zero and **DID NOT** shut off is troubling information and should be an indicator this switch is faulty.  Time to replace.  Your picture appears to be an OYKC-5. This is a 60 minute timer for a SKSM Saunatec heater.

I would think your best bet to locate a new sauna timer would be from a sauna supplier as opposed to an electrical supply house.

Answer (score 2):

> The last time I used it, when I turned it all the way to 60 min, it shut off, so I backed it off a bit. It ran to 0, but did not shut off. I think I need to replace it.

That sounds kind of like normal behavior for a mechanical spring-wound timer, honestly.  If you dial the control too far, it may shut off.

And on the sign there should have been a warning that says "Turn past..." That's because that force you need to turn it *gets stored in a large spring* and is used to operate the contacts.  Certain combinations of handle movement can leave the spring with not enough residual energy to throw the switch.  That's why you can't set it to "2 minutes" and expect it to work.

So I would see if the timer resumes operating properly in future uses, and if it does, don't worry about it.  If the timer needs replacement, that's a bit complicated because normal timers are only rated 15-20 amps, and the electronic ones need 120V which won't be available at the sauna. This seems like a specialty thing.  Helping people source things is off-topic on this site.

Comment: Thank you. I will try it again.